# Formidable forms radio button styling

Tags: html, css, forms, input, radio-button

I'm struggling with Formidable Forms radio-input styling.

Formidable Forms wraps the label around the input[type="radio"] which makes it hard to style when the input is checked.

What I want is the radio-circle to be hidden and instead I want a box around the input which changes color when the input is checked.

This is the current generated code:

```
<label for="field_9g6u4-5">
<input type="radio" name="item_meta[10]" id="field_9g6u4-5" value="2.00" data-sectionid="27">
2.00
</label>
```

Comment: [Customize HTML](https://formidableforms.com/knowledgebase/customize-html/) Think of it the other way around, instead of styling the `<label>` which is just a semantic wrapper, style the adjacent `<span class="val">2.00</span>` like `[type=radio]:checked ~ .val {}` PS: just as a quick idea, I'm not familiar with Formidable :\ but I **always** prefer using `<label>` as a wrapper for input and other *replacement* elements - when creating custom inputs.